# Flickr API Search?

Tags: php, api, flickr

I have some php code that retrieves a set of images based of a photoset. I want to manipulate this code so that it grabs a set of pictures from a search term.

I know you can use the method inbuilt into the api: flickr.photos.search

Just wondering how i can apply it to this code

```
 <?php
  $params = array(
'api_key'   => '2292bec0973f91d9f62fb606f85ee031',
'method'    => 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
'photoset_id'   => '72157622566216264',
'extras'    => 'original_format',
'format'    => 'php_serial'
  );
  $encoded_params = array();
  foreach ($params as $k => $v){ $encoded_params[] = urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v); }

   $ch = curl_init();
   $timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?'.implode('&',             $encoded_params));
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
   $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   $rsp_obj = unserialize($file_contents);

   if ($rsp_obj['stat'] == 'ok') {

    $photos = $rsp_obj["photoset"]["photo"];

echo "
     <ul>";

foreach($photos as $photo) {

           $farm              = $photo['farm'];
           $server            = $photo['server'];
           $photo_id          = $photo['id'];
           $secret            = $photo['secret'];
           $photo_title       = $photo['title'];

         echo '<li><img          src="http://farm'.$photo['farm'].'.static.flickr.com/'.$photo['server'].'/'.$photo['id'].'_'.$photo['secret'].'_t.jpg" alt="'.$photo['title'].'" ></li>';

     }
       echo "
           </ul>

            ";

} else {
        echo "Error getting photos";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: This question is pretty hard to answer. You provide a code snippet with no insight on how much you know about it and how much you pretend from the answer.

Comment: This is all the code - This specific code grabs an array of pictures from flickr from a photoset defined in the params array. These parameters are then imploded onto the url to retrieve the images. Ive tried to alter it so that instead of looking for a photoset ID it looks for a search tag, and goes through the method flickr.photos.search. Which is prebuilt into the api. I thought it would be a simple swapping of certain variables as grabbing the photos is surely the same no matter what method you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the documentation? [flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html)

These methods return similar data, but the name of the top-level array is different (**photos** vs. **photoset**). Assuming you modified your parameters to use the correct method and pass the appropriate arguments, the only other thing you need to change is this line:

```
$photos = $rsp_obj["photos"]["photo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query url:

http://flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=YOUR-KEY&text=YOUR-SEARCH TERM&per_page=10&format=php_serial